# Run & Debug yo gulp-angular & typescript

Tags: debugging, gulp, webstorm, typescript1.4

I used `yo gulp-angular` (https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) generator to create my `typescript/angular/gulp` project. Everything works fine in a command lenter code hereine and I can run projects easily. But, have some issues running & debugging typescipt in web storm 10.0.4

I am trying to run `gulp serve` in debug mode (in run mode it starts well) and getting message `Debugger listening on port 58032`and nothing happening.

Are there any comprehensive guide, how to debug & run `gulp` based typescript
`enter code here`projects with web storm or other IDE? What is the best IDE for this kind of setup?

thanks

Comment: I am trying to get it to work with Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com) and have the same issue. The `gulp serve` task just runs BrowserSync but no node process to attach the debugger to. Any help is very much appreciated as I am running out of ideas. BTW starting the node process manually won't work (i.e. `node --debug=5858 src/app/index.ts` nor with the JS files `node --debug=5858 .tmp/serve/app/index.js`)

Comment: BTW, as it is a similar question but geared towards a different IDE (Visual Studio Code), I created a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310957/debugging-gulp-angular-generated-typescript-apps-in-visual-studio-code. Hopefully it gets some attention by the VSC developers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familar with Webstorm but I use the Swiip Gulp Angular Generator and by default the browsersync instance will run on port 3000(or the next available port) so I'm guessing if you set the ports to the same value you will get the Webstorm debugging working

To change the port for the Gulp Serve task, go under gulp/server.js

```
browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
  startPath: '/',
  port: 58032,
  server: server,
  browser: browser
});
```

Comment: How do you debug typescript and what IDE are you using? I am not really bounded to web storm,  I am looking for a ide with sophisticated autocomplete and debugging options.

Comment: I'm predominately a UI Designer/Developer and don't do a lot of complex JS coding so I don't really need a debugger as a result I just want something fast which allows me to create clean code, so I use Sublime Text or more recently Atom. That said Ive heard good things about Webstorm, so if I were to look at a using a debugger I would choose Webstorm

Comment: Well, Chrome is a great debugging tool. If you have map files you can debug typescript with no effort.

Answer (score 0):

Running `gulp serve` in Debug mode means that WebStorm would start a Node.js debug session for your task. If you want to debug your client-side code you need to start a new JavaScript debug session for the URL: http://localhost:3000/. Make sure that you have all your source maps in place.